# PHP MySql get results from two talbes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am developing a chat app in PHP. Where I want to get latest conversations thread in a DESC order based on time. So latest conversation threads in comes first.

In MySql One table contains messages with thread_ids and another table contains thread_ids and recipient_ids od that thread

### First table (`zeb_bp_messages_messages`)

[image]

### Second table(`zeb_bp_messages_recipients`)

[image]

In the first picture you can see multiple same thread ids with a sender_id(`most in cases there is 2 sender ids for a thread`). I want to grab the latest ones from multiple rows. I was successful doing this. But I need to get lastest ones from either of the two senders.

I did this one but in vein :

```
global $wpdb;
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
$threads = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT thread_id, MAX(id) FROM {$wpdb->base_prefix}bp_messages_messages WHERE sender_id={$current_user_id} GROUP BY thread_id ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC");
```

SHould i use `INNER JOIN` or something else??